# Good quality audio conferencing without a headset

Tags: voip, speakers, conferencing, microphone

I work at home and am doing a lot more video conferencing than I used to.  I also use a softphone on the computer for most of my phone calls as well.  Particularly when video conferencing I would like to not wear a headset, or find an ultralight headset of good quality.

What are other home professionals using for non-headset video conferencing?  I currently have a Logitech 9000 webcam.  The video is just fine for our needs, but I don't think the mic cuts it.  It also picks up sounds from my speakers.  So I think this might be more than just replacing the mic, but also how to best place the mic and speakers to avoid echo.  Someone thought that a Blue Yeti mic may be an improvement, but I'm worried about it picking up the sounds through the speakers.

So the question.. Good mic/speaker setup for headset free communications in a home office?  What are you recommendations for equipment as well as placement.

Computer is a Mac.

Comment: There are plenty of bluetooth headsets that are nice for video conferencing because of the wireless aspect, such as this: http://www.amazon.com/Cobra-CBTH1-Bluetooth-Cancellation-Technology/dp/B002ATG4TA  or this: http://www.amazon.com/Andrea-Headsets-Bluetooth-Cancelling-Frequency/dp/B005MUXP5U/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1318612694&sr=8-1  As far as headset free goes, there are noise cancelling mic options such as this: http://www.amazon.com/Logitech-Desktop-Microphone-Black-Silver/dp/B00009EHJV

Comment: +1 For bluetooth headsets. Simply put, you're never going to achieve as good quality without a headset or mic than with one. Bluetooth headsets are extremely light and costs as much as a moderate-quality gaming headset